# Rediculus proof of $[L\vec a,\vec b] = L[\vec a,\vec b]$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I want to know are my conclusions right. I need to proof that $[L\vec a,\vec b] = L[\vec a,\vec b]= [\vec a,L\vec b]$. So:

In case were $L = 0 $ or $\vec a || \vec b$ we have $(\vec 0 = \vec 0)$. In other cases we have can choose two perpendicular planes such that $\vec a \in \alpha, \vec a \in \beta, \vec b \in \beta$, then by knowing the value of modul of vector multiplycation
$$
[\vec a,\vec b] = R^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\vec a) |\vec b|sin(\vec a,\vec b)
$$
so that
$$
[\vec a,L\vec b] = R^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\vec a) |L\vec b|sin(\vec a,L\vec b) = [\vec a,L\vec b] = LR^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\vec a) |\vec b|sin(\vec a,\vec b)
$$
the manipulations for brining $L$ out of first position are the same, and for negative $L$ the sin will get negative value.

Can I use this proof, or I have a mistake?

Comment: I don't understand your notation. What is $L$? What does $R^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ mean? And so on.

Comment: $L$ is a real number and $R^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is a rotation on $\frac{\pi}{2}$